# How to sort QList according to a certain order (not alphabetical)?

Tags: qt, sorting, qsort, qlist

I have `QList<m_User>` with

```
m_User {
    QString status;
    QString firstName;
    QString lastName;
    QDate joinDate;
    QDate leaveDate;
}
```

`status` here can be: `terminated`, `in test`, `requested`, `activated`.

The order of sorting for `status` should be: `activated` -> `terminated` -> `requested` -> `in test`

This QList should be sorted according to this order:

1. status (with order like above)
2. if status is same, we sort firstName, this time alphabetically
3. if firstName is same, we sort lastName, also alphabetically

So the result should look like

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| firstName | lastName |  status  | joinDate | leaveDate |
----------------------------------------------------------
|     A     |    C     |activated |   bla    |    bla    |
|     A     |    D     |activated |   bla    |    bla    | 
|     B     |    E     |activated |   bla    |    bla    |

|     A     |    F     |terminated|   bla    |    bla    | 
|     A     |    G     |terminated|   bla    |    bla    | 
|     B     |    H     |terminated|   bla    |    bla    |

|     A     |    I     |requested |   bla    |    bla    | 
|     B     |    I     |requested |   bla    |    bla    | 
|     B     |    K     |requested |   bla    |    bla    |

|     A     |    L     | in test  |   bla    |    bla    |  
|     B     |    L     | in test  |   bla    |    bla    |
|     B     |    M     | in test  |   bla    |    bla    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    bool compareUsers(const m_User &u1, const m_User &u2)
    {
        if(u1.status != u2.status)
        {
            //compare all possible combination if statuses of the
            //u1 user and u2 user and return which has priority

            //example activated has priorty over terminated
            if(u1.status == "activated" && u2.status =="terminated")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(u1.status == "terminated" && u2.status =="activated")
            {
                return false;
            }
            ...
            ..
            .
        }
        else if(u1.firstName != u2.firstName)
        {
            return u1.firstName > u2.firstName;
        }
        else
        {
           return u1.lastName > u2.lastName; 
        }
    }
```

and then just call the predicate in sort function

```
QList<m_User> list;
qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), compareUsers);
```

Comment: wow, your solution is easy to understand :). Here I have 4 statuses, it means it should have 6 pairs of statues to compare, isn't it?

Comment: You can store all available statuses in a `QStringList`, and use the [`QStringList::indexOf`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#indexOf) method to get the index. Then you can just compare the indexes. This will save you the trouble of having a bunch of `if` `else if` statements.

Comment: Yes @thuga give you a great idea you have my solution you just need to implement. It is simply and easy :)

Comment: thanks you guys. I accepted this solution. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: @thuga For this line `qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), compareUsers);` I got this error message `Error 25 error C3867: 'QcgMainLogic::compareUsers': function call missing argument list; use '&QcgMainLogic::compareUsers' to create a pointer to member`. Do you know guys what it means?
`

Comment: @Angel.Risteski Should I define in header `compareUsers` as `static`, and then `qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), &compareUsers);` ?

Comment: You [should use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qt-and-the-stl-algorithms) *(as it has already been pointed out in the other answer)*. Either make your member function a static member, or just make it a non-member function.

Comment: thank you @thuga . I think the problem here should be about `static`. because I also used `std::sort` already, just forgot to write. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can add lessThen function to your class/struct and then if needed create forwarder for qSort.
Example:

```
class m_User {
public:
bool operator<(const m_User other) const {
        return a<other.a;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ForwardLessThen
{     
  bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const     
  {
    return *a < *b;
  } 
}; 

qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), ForwardLessThen<m_User>());
```

if you use C++11/14 you can use lambdas

```
QList<const m_User*> l;
qSort(l.begin(), l.end(), 
      [](const m_User* a, const m_User* b) -> bool { return a->firstName() < b->firstName(); //implement your logic here
});
```

With Qt5 qSort is actually deprecated and you should use std::sort function.

```
std::sort(container.begin(), container.end(), qLess<T>());
```

Take a look at template-based algorithms in [QtAlgorithms](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html)

**EDIT:** Or if you plan using some kind of View Models(like ListView) you can even implement own [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html)

Comment: thank you. No, this view is just easier for you guys to imagine. I still can not imagine how should my logic be for sorting `status` with lambdas :(

Comment: why don't you just compare the strings? And use some if-else states after that... http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#compare

Comment: thanks for your support. I am new to this field, so the answer of Angel is easier for me to perform, so I accepted it. I also upvoted your answer. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Looks like `qLess()` is also deprecated

Comment: as qLess() is deprecated, use std::less()